# Python log(n) complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

I cannot understand why this is a log(n) complexity code.

```
def intToStr(i):
    digits = '0123456789'
    if i == 0:
        return '0'
    result = ''
    while i > 0:
        print(1)
        result = digits[i%10] + result
        i = i//10
    return result
```

Comment: calculate how many cycle iterations this would take for 1, 10, 100, ..., 10 billion, plot cycle iterations against the numbers entered and see which function this looks like

Comment: Generally, you don't care about the base of the logarithm. `log(n, x)` and `log(n, y)` only differ by a constant factor.

Comment: ok, I changed the title, so nobody gets confused abouth log(n,10), thanks @chepner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Abhihit's answer, you need to calculate the amount of steps:

```
while i > 0:
    i = i // 10
```

will take. Well suppose you start at i = n. The amount of steps is the amount of times a product of 10 will 'fit' in `i` (since you divide out 10 each time). This is the digit mentioned above. So the relation between the amount of steps and n is:

```
n=10^steps
```

There is a 'leftover' or modulues, but in integer division it doesn't matter (it may add 1 to the steps). So solving for steps:

```
steps=log n
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop/algorithm is a function of a number of digits in a number<sup>#</sup>. Considering, we are dealing with a decimal and for a number `n` the digit count is given as `log`<sub>10</sub>`(n) + 1`, we can assume without loss of generality that the complexity of this algorithm is `log`<sub>10</sub>`(n) + 1` as the constant `1` is invariant.

`#`:

```
while i > 0:
    i = i // 10
```

loops for number of digits in `i` as on each iteration it sheds one digit until the number is `0`.